# Type hint for Ellipsis

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, ellipsis

How can I specify a type hint for a function that expects a literal `Ellipsis` (or `...`) as an argument? In analogy with `None`, I'm tempted to write something like:

```py
def f(x: Ellipsis):
    return

f(Ellipsis)
```

If I run this through `mypy`, however, I get:

```
1: error: Variable "builtins.Ellipsis" is not valid as a type
```

`mypy` is happy with the following:

```
import builtins

def f(x: builtins.ellipsis):
    return


f(Ellipsis)
```

But this fails at runtime with:

```
AttributeError: module 'builtins' has no attribute 'ellipsis'.
```

Comment: a hack, but import `builtins` and try `"builtins.Ellipsis"` I could have sworn they were going to expose this type somewhere, but it would be in a very recent version of Python

Comment: In lieu of a proper type, `Literal[Ellipsis]` may do the job

Comment: import types; types.EllipsisType?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Tried that, mypy still complains...

Comment: @Brian will give it a go.

Comment: @jsbueno ah, sounds like that's probably what I'm after.

Comment: @Kyle sorry, I meant `"builtins.ellipsis"`, which could still be a workaround in Python < 3.10

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that's not importable, at least not from builtins, it just defined `Ellipsis` - I can't find anywhere that the class definition for `<class 'ellipsis'>` is actually exposed in python<3.10, which is of course the crux of the problem.

Comment: @Kyle You don't *need* to import it. You just need to use `import builtins` then use `"builtins.ellipsis"`. AFAIKT, it works for mypy at least. That type wasn't exposed prior to Python 3.10, I'm pretty sure

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga see the snippet in my question. You're right that mypy is satisfied, but the interpreter is *not*.

Comment: @Kyle the interpreter **is fine with it**. Please notice that I am suggesting you use the *string* `"builtins.ellipsis"`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah, my brain silently dropped the quotes. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by [jsbueno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108205/jsbueno), the following works as of python 3.10:

```py
from types import EllipsisType


def f(x: EllipsisType):
    return

f(Ellipsis)
```